mkpasswd/crypt yescrypt does not accept long salts
I am trying to create password hashes using mkpasswd, passing to it a (256+13)bit long salt as follows:
rand=$(openssl rand -base64 256)        # Creating random data, base64-formatted.

# Concatenating the password type (yescrypt) with the parameters (j9T) with 
# the random data for our Salt
salt="\$y\$j9T\$$rand"

# Generating the password (including the $y$ means we don't have to specify 
# the algorithm)
passwd=$(mkpasswd $password -S "$salt")          

When I run it, I get this error, crypt: Invalid argument
How can I pass a 256-bit long salt to mkpasswd yescrypt?
Versions:
mkpasswd 5.5.20

What is your goal in wanting a salt that large? 128 bits is enough to virtually guarantee global uniqueness, which is the purpose of salting. The salt size was "overly" large by design, and larger salts have no additional security value. Further, what is your goal in trying to create the salt externally? The implementation is designed to do that for you, precisely to prevent weakness due to misapprehension of the security properties of the algorithm. If you are trying to generate your own salts, you're doing it wrong.

@RoyceWilliams Hello mister Williams, thank you for your comment. Firstly, I thought that openssl-rand generates bits, not bytes; this why I specified 256. Secondly, I did not know that it generates salts by itself if not specified. Thank you for informing me, I'll adjust the script at once.

@RoyceWilliams I am noticing that the mkpasswd generates a 29-bytes long salt, is there a way to specify 256-byes long salt?

Note that with that quoting, your salt would be the literal 15-byte long string \$y\$j9T\$$rand. The shell would not expand $rand nor treat backslashes in any special way within single quotes. Also, the argument "$y$" to mkpasswd would most likely expand to just $ as the variable y has no value in your script.  With $password unquoted, any whitespace would split it into multiple arguments, and any globbing character may pull in pathnames from the filesystem. Correct these syntax-related errors and check that your issue remains.

@Kusalananda Hello, mister Kusalananda. Thank you for pointing out these syntax-related errors. I have figured out the error and posted it in the answer below. The error was with that mkpasswd expected a 16-bytes or 32-bytes long salt, and I gave it a 263-bytes long.

There are two reasons for this behavior.

One of them is that openssl rand generates bytes, not bits. To generate a 256-bit long salt, one would run openssl rand -base64 32.

The other is that the salt is expected to be 32-bytes long (i.e., 256-bit long) or (16-1)-bytes long (i.e., 128-bit long). This means that you'll need to account for the 7-bytes prefix (i.e., $y$j9T$).

The tests I ran only worked for 16-bytes long and 32-bytes long, I do not know whether other values are accepted.

Alternatively, you can simply use mkpasswd <secret> -m yescrypt and it'll generate the salt for you.
